# Is there a good way to append words in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, append, keyvaluepair

Here is an example.

**DataSet - dataset.txt**

`1 banana kiwi orange melon`

**Code**

```
scala> val table = sc.textFile("dataset.txt").map(_.split(" "))

scala> table.take(1)

res0: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(1, banana , kiwi , orange, melon))

scala> val pairSet = table.map{case Array(key,b,k,o,m) => (key, b+" "+k+" "+o+" "+m)}

scala> pairSet.take(1)

res1: Array[(String, String)] = Array((1, banana kiwi orange melon))
```

I wonder if the part that appends the values in the `pairSet` is efficient. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

you can split by first occurrence of space & create `key` & `value` from it.

```
val table = sc.textFile("dataset.txt").map { x =>
  val splits = x.split(" ",2)
  (splits(0), splits(1))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Is your method`(val splits = x.split(" ",2)
  (splits(0), splits(1)))` more efficient than my method`(b+" "+k+" "+o+" "+m)`?

Comment: yes, because in your case, you are splitting the remaining strings except the first occurrence unnecessarily only to again append them later.

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you very much for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach for logic will only work if the array always has same amount of data in it. You can also try this.

```
val table = sc.textFile("dataset.txt")
val pairedDF = table.map{ line =>
                        val array = line.split(" ", 2)
                        (array(0), array(1))
                        }
```

By using this there you are not restricting the array to be of fixed sized after splitting.

Hope this works fine for you.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Is your method`(val array = line.split(" ", 2)
                        (array(0), array(1)))` more efficient than my method`(b+" "+k+" "+o+" "+m)`?

Comment: Yes because it[loop] stop splitting the value after it gets the first space.

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you very much for your advice!